# How to set required attribute for an input field in DatePicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I'm generating `Kendo's Datepicker` in my `MVC` application.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
  .Name("FileDate")
  .Value(Session["FileDate"] == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(Session["FileDate"].ToString()))
  .Events(e => e
          .Change("datepicker_change")
  )
)
```

When generated, I have an input field:
[image]

How can I update my code to add `required` attribute to an `input` field?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a Model defined in the View, then you can decorate `FileDate` model field with [Required] DataAnnotation. Thus the extension will extract the data validation attributes automatically.

The second option is to add the `required` HTML attribute using the HtmlAttributes (or the InputHtmlAttributes I'm not sure what was the correct name). This will add the defined attributes to the corresponding HTML element.